# How to shorten a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have this jQuery function that work. Every 2 lines is the same except a minor changes. How can I shorten it?

```
$(".c1").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $("#phone").addClass("c2").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(".c2").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#phone").addClass("c3").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                $(".c3").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#phone").addClass("c4").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                        $(".c4").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                            $("#phone").addClass("c5").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                $(".c5").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                                    $("#phone").addClass("c6").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                        $(".c6").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                                            $("#phone").addClass("c7").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                                $(".c7").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                                                    $("#phone").addClass("c8").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                                        $(".c8").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                                                            $("#phone").addClass("c9").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                                                $(".c9").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                                                                    $("#phone").addClass("c1").fadeIn("slow");
                                                                });
                                                            });
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `+1` That's a big **arrow** out there! `:)`

Comment: What does the html look like? A Global class may solve this monstrous js :)

Comment: Have a look at this link http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/ It looks like exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Because I know jQuery for 2 hours..

Comment: @UrielFrankel Can you please give us the HTML and what you are trying to achieve? PLeasE? I feel this can be done easily!

Comment: @PraveenKumar This is the link for my web site. http://urielfra.appspot.com It is a site I built in order to learn Google App Engine.

Comment: There's something odd here. Is the `#phone` element the only one that gets the `.c_` class? Because if there are others, they never fade In.

Comment: Look in my website. The phone on the left changes backgrounds. I very new to all the HTML/CSS/jQuery etc. stuff, so I probably do not do things the right way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a recursive function like this:

```
function phoneCall(i){
    $(".c" + i).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#phone").addClass("c" + (i + 1)).fadeIn("slow", function() {
            if(i <= 9) phoneCall(i + 1);
        });
    });            
} 
phoneCall(1);
```

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `#phone` element is the only one that ever gets the `c_` class. If so, you can cache the element and eliminate a bunch of code.

```
var phone = $("#phone"), i = 0;

(function cycle() {
    i = ((i % 9) + 1);
    phone.addClass("c" + i).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", cycle);
})();
```

---

We can even get rid of a line of code by inlining the increment.

```
var phone = $("#phone"), i = 0;

(function cycle() {
    phone.addClass("c" + ((++i % 9) + 1)).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", cycle);
})();
```

---

As [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) noted, you may not want it to infinitely loop. If not, add a `return` statement.

```
var phone = $("#phone"), i = 0;

(function cycle() {
    if (i === 9) return;
    phone.addClass("c" + ((++i % 9) + 1)).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", cycle);
})();
```

---

And FWIW, numbering is usually a little simpler if you use `0` based indices.

```
var phone = $("#phone"), i = -1;

(function cycle() {
    phone.addClass("c" + (++i % 9)).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", cycle);
})();
```

Comment: @UrielFrankel: An misplaced variable from a previous version of my answer. I'll fix it. It should be the total number of `c` classes.

Comment: one difference is this will loop forever whereas OP won't but +1 for short and sweet.

Comment: @charlietfl: You're absolutely right. For some reason I assumed that was the intent. It would seem like it from the website, but maybe that's not the case.

Comment: @user1689607 I have no idea either , just pointing it out. I'm also guessing that all the extra classes don't do much other than hide the element which could be easily done with `hide()`

Comment: @UrielFrankel: Are you using the `i` variable in the same scope? If so, change `i` to a better name. I have no problem with it crashing.

Comment: @UrielFrankel: Here's a slightly different version. It does a `.removeClass()` as well so we don't end up with a long list of classes. http://jsfiddle.net/3YJRB/

Comment: Nice! I will try this tomorrow. Guys you are Awsome, I wish I could give "accept" to all of you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that:

```
function inception(fromInt, tillInt){
    if (fromInt < tillInt){
        $('.c' + fromInt).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow",function(){
            newInt = fromInt +1;
            $('#phone').addClass('c'+newInt).fadeIn("slow", function() {
                inception(newInt, tillInt));
            }
        });
    }else{
        if(fromint == tillInt){
            $('.c' + fromInt).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }
}
```

Then add to your code:

```
inception(1,9);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know something like this?

```
var num = 2;

var HandlerForC = function () {
    if (num < 10) {
        $("#phone").addClass("c" + num).fadeIn("slow", HandlerForPhone);
    } else {
        $("#phone").addClass("c1").fadeIn("slow");
    }

}

var HandlerForPhone = function () {
    num++;
    $(".c" + (num - 1)).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", HandlerForC);
}
HandlerForPhone();
```